# Circular barplot from r-graph-gallery with error: “Aesthetics must be either length 1...”

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to reproduce a complex circular bar chart described in this tutorial ([Link](https://r-graph-gallery.com/297-circular-barplot-with-groups.html)). However, although the script is adaptable, when I increase the number of groups beyond what is described in the tutorial (from 4 to 8 groups by adding E, F, G and H), I get the following error: “Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (8): hjust”.

I studied about this error and I know it is related to the amount of colors and groups. But looking at the script, "fill" seems to be organized correctly, without limiting the amount of colors.

I hope it can help me to escape this error.

**My code (not working)**

```
# library
library(tidyverse)

# Create dataset
data <- data.frame(
  individual=paste( "Mister ", seq(1,60), sep=""),
  group=factor(c(rep('A', 10), rep('B', 10), rep('C', 10), rep('D', 10),
                 rep('E', 5), rep('F', 5), rep('G', 5), rep('H', 5))),
  value=sample( seq(10,100), 60, replace=T)
)

# Set a number of 'empty bar' to add at the end of each group
empty_bar <- 2
to_add <- data.frame( matrix(NA, empty_bar*nlevels(data$group), ncol(data)) )
colnames(to_add) <- colnames(data)
to_add$group <- rep(levels(data$group), each=empty_bar)
data <- rbind(data, to_add)
data <- data %>% arrange(group)
data$id <- seq(1, nrow(data))

# Get the name and the y position of each label
label_data <- data
number_of_bar <- nrow(label_data)
angle <- 90 - 360 * (label_data$id-0.5) /number_of_bar     # I substract 0.5 because the letter must have the angle of the center of the bars. Not extreme right(1) or extreme left (0)
label_data$hjust <- ifelse( angle < -90, 1, 0)
label_data$angle <- ifelse(angle < -90, angle+180, angle)

# prepare a data frame for base lines
base_data <- data %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  summarize(start=min(id), end=max(id) - empty_bar) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(title=mean(c(start, end)))

# prepare a data frame for grid (scales)
grid_data <- base_data
grid_data$end <- grid_data$end[ c( nrow(grid_data), 1:nrow(grid_data)-1)] + 1
grid_data$start <- grid_data$start - 1
grid_data <- grid_data[-1,]

# Make the plot
p <- ggplot(data, aes(x=as.factor(id), y=value, fill=group)) +       # Note that id is a factor. If x is numeric, there is some space between the first bar
  
  geom_bar(aes(x=as.factor(id), y=value, fill=group), stat="identity", alpha=0.5) +
  
  # Add a val=100/75/50/25 lines. I do it at the beginning to make sur barplots are OVER it.
  geom_segment(data=grid_data, aes(x = end, y = 80, xend = start, yend = 80), colour = "grey", alpha=1, size=0.3 , inherit.aes = FALSE ) +
  geom_segment(data=grid_data, aes(x = end, y = 70, xend = start, yend = 70), colour = "grey", alpha=1, size=0.3 , inherit.aes = FALSE ) +
  geom_segment(data=grid_data, aes(x = end, y = 60, xend = start, yend = 60), colour = "grey", alpha=1, size=0.3 , inherit.aes = FALSE ) +
  geom_segment(data=grid_data, aes(x = end, y = 50, xend = start, yend = 50), colour = "grey", alpha=1, size=0.3 , inherit.aes = FALSE ) +
  geom_segment(data=grid_data, aes(x = end, y = 40, xend = start, yend = 40), colour = "grey", alpha=1, size=0.3 , inherit.aes = FALSE ) +
  geom_segment(data=grid_data, aes(x = end, y = 30, xend = start, yend = 30), colour = "grey", alpha=1, size=0.3 , inherit.aes = FALSE ) +
  geom_segment(data=grid_data, aes(x = end, y = 20, xend = start, yend = 20), colour = "grey", alpha=1, size=0.3 , inherit.aes = FALSE ) +
  geom_segment(data=grid_data, aes(x = end, y = 10, xend = start, yend = 10), colour = "grey", alpha=1, size=0.3 , inherit.aes = FALSE ) +
  
  # Add text showing the value of each 100/75/50/25 lines
  annotate("text", x = rep(max(data$id),8), y = c(10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80), label = c("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8") , color="grey", size=3 , angle=0, fontface="bold", hjust=1) +
  
  geom_bar(aes(x=as.factor(id), y=value, fill=group), stat="identity", alpha=0.5) +
  ylim(-100,120) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    legend.position = "none",
    axis.text = element_blank(),
    axis.title = element_blank(),
    panel.grid = element_blank(),
    plot.margin = unit(rep(-1,4), "cm")
  ) +
  coord_polar() + 
  geom_text(data=label_data, aes(x=id, y=value+10, label=individual, hjust=hjust), color="black", fontface="bold",alpha=0.6, size=2.5, angle= label_data$angle, inherit.aes = FALSE ) +
  
  # Add base line information
  geom_segment(data=base_data, aes(x = start, y = -5, xend = end, yend = -5), colour = "black", alpha=0.8, size=0.6 , inherit.aes = FALSE )  +
  geom_text(data=base_data, aes(x = title, y = -18, label=group), hjust=c(1,1,0,0), colour = "black", alpha=0.8, size=4, fontface="bold", inherit.aes = FALSE)

p
```

**Tutorial code (working)**

```
# library
library(tidyverse)

# Create dataset
data <- data.frame(
  individual=paste( "Mister ", seq(1,60), sep=""),
  group=factor(c(rep('A', 10), rep('B', 30), rep('C', 14), rep('D', 6))),
  value=sample( seq(10,100), 60, replace=T)
)

# Set a number of 'empty bar' to add at the end of each group
empty_bar <- 3
to_add <- data.frame( matrix(NA, empty_bar*nlevels(data$group), ncol(data)) )
colnames(to_add) <- colnames(data)
to_add$group <- rep(levels(data$group), each=empty_bar)
data <- rbind(data, to_add)
data <- data %>% arrange(group)
data$id <- seq(1, nrow(data))

# Get the name and the y position of each label
label_data <- data
number_of_bar <- nrow(label_data)
angle <- 90 - 360 * (label_data$id-0.5) /number_of_bar     # I substract 0.5 because the letter must have the angle of the center of the bars. Not extreme right(1) or extreme left (0)
label_data$hjust <- ifelse( angle < -90, 1, 0)
label_data$angle <- ifelse(angle < -90, angle+180, angle)

# prepare a data frame for base lines
base_data <- data %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  summarize(start=min(id), end=max(id) - empty_bar) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(title=mean(c(start, end)))

# prepare a data frame for grid (scales)
grid_data <- base_data
grid_data$end <- grid_data$end[ c( nrow(grid_data), 1:nrow(grid_data)-1)] + 1
grid_data$start <- grid_data$start - 1
grid_data <- grid_data[-1,]

# Make the plot
p <- ggplot(data, aes(x=as.factor(id), y=value, fill=group)) +       # Note that id is a factor. If x is numeric, there is some space between the first bar
  
  geom_bar(aes(x=as.factor(id), y=value, fill=group), stat="identity", alpha=0.5) +
  
  # Add a val=100/75/50/25 lines. I do it at the beginning to make sur barplots are OVER it.
  geom_segment(data=grid_data, aes(x = end, y = 80, xend = start, yend = 80), colour = "grey", alpha=1, size=0.3 , inherit.aes = FALSE ) +
  geom_segment(data=grid_data, aes(x = end, y = 60, xend = start, yend = 60), colour = "grey", alpha=1, size=0.3 , inherit.aes = FALSE ) +
  geom_segment(data=grid_data, aes(x = end, y = 40, xend = start, yend = 40), colour = "grey", alpha=1, size=0.3 , inherit.aes = FALSE ) +
  geom_segment(data=grid_data, aes(x = end, y = 20, xend = start, yend = 20), colour = "grey", alpha=1, size=0.3 , inherit.aes = FALSE ) +
  
  # Add text showing the value of each 100/75/50/25 lines
  annotate("text", x = rep(max(data$id),4), y = c(20, 40, 60, 80), label = c("20", "40", "60", "80") , color="grey", size=3 , angle=0, fontface="bold", hjust=1) +
  
  geom_bar(aes(x=as.factor(id), y=value, fill=group), stat="identity", alpha=0.5) +
  ylim(-100,120) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    legend.position = "none",
    axis.text = element_blank(),
    axis.title = element_blank(),
    panel.grid = element_blank(),
    plot.margin = unit(rep(-1,4), "cm") 
  ) +
  coord_polar() + 
  geom_text(data=label_data, aes(x=id, y=value+10, label=individual, hjust=hjust), color="black", fontface="bold",alpha=0.6, size=2.5, angle= label_data$angle, inherit.aes = FALSE ) +
  
  # Add base line information
  geom_segment(data=base_data, aes(x = start, y = -5, xend = end, yend = -5), colour = "black", alpha=0.8, size=0.6 , inherit.aes = FALSE )  +
  geom_text(data=base_data, aes(x = title, y = -18, label=group), hjust=c(1,1,0,0), colour = "black", alpha=0.8, size=4, fontface="bold", inherit.aes = FALSE)

p
```

[image]

Comment: The clue is in the error message.  It's something to do with `hjust` not having 8 values.  You've added 4 new groups, so I'm going to look got a place where `hjust` has 4 elements rather than 8.  It's here:  `hjust=c(1,1,0,0)`.  So I changed this to `hjust=c(1,1,0,0, 1, 1, 0, 0)` and got a plot.  Whether those are the correct new values, you will have to decide.

Comment: Thanks! Simple and objective!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that in the last `geom_text` which adds the group labels you pass a vector of length 4 to `hjust`. However, as you have 8 groups you have to pass a vector of length 8. Additionally I simplified you code a bit by using `lapply` to add your segment layers:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = as.factor(id), y = value, fill = group)) + # Note that id is a factor. If x is numeric, there is some space between the first bar
  geom_bar(aes(x = as.factor(id), y = value, fill = group), stat = "identity", alpha = 0.5) +
  # Add a val=100/75/50/25 lines. I do it at the beginning to make sur barplots are OVER it.
  lapply(seq(8), function(x) {
    geom_segment(data = grid_data, aes(x = end, y = 10 * x, xend = start, yend = 10 * x), colour = "grey", alpha = 1, size = 0.3, inherit.aes = FALSE)  
  }) +
  # Add text showing the value of each 100/75/50/25 lines
  annotate("text", x = rep(max(data$id), 8), y = c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80), label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"), color = "grey", size = 3, angle = 0, fontface = "bold", hjust = 1) +
  geom_bar(aes(x = as.factor(id), y = value, fill = group), stat = "identity", alpha = 0.5) +
  ylim(-100, 120) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    legend.position = "none",
    axis.text = element_blank(),
    axis.title = element_blank(),
    panel.grid = element_blank(),
    plot.margin = unit(rep(-1, 4), "cm")
  ) +
  coord_polar() +
  geom_text(data = label_data, aes(x = id, y = value + 10, label = individual, hjust = hjust), color = "black", fontface = "bold", alpha = 0.6, size = 2.5, angle = label_data$angle, inherit.aes = FALSE) +
  # Add base line information
  geom_segment(data = base_data, aes(x = start, y = -5, xend = end, yend = -5), colour = "black", alpha = 0.8, size = 0.6, inherit.aes = FALSE) +
  geom_text(data = base_data, aes(x = title, y = -18, label = group), hjust = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
            colour = "black", alpha = 0.8, size = 4, fontface = "bold", inherit.aes = FALSE)
```

[image]